# CKEditor 4 removes &nbsp; from <p> and <div> tags that have no text

Tags: ckeditor4.x

**How to disable &nbsp automatic removal from p and div tags that have no text? Below is an example:**

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>   =>   <p></p>
```

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>   =>   <div></div>
```

**If the tag has text, this does not happen:**

```
<p>text&nbsp;</p>   =>   <p>text&nbsp;</p>
```

```
<div>text&nbsp;</div>   =>   <div>text&nbsp;</div>
```

**This situation does not occur with the <span> tag:**

```
<span>&nbsp;</span>   =>   <span>&nbsp;</span>
```